# Why does "Rancunes et partis" translate into "And enmity and spouses" to English in Vive Henri Quatre?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, expressions, paroles-de-chanson

I've been listening to some renaissance music and I stumbled upon the so called first french national anthem, and while listening I heard a few lyrics that confused me so I looked them up. But one confuses me a lot and that one is

> Rancunes et partis

Which I think, translates into "Grudge, and leave!" but it translates (according to wikipedia) into "And enmity and spouses". There's also

> Comme nos pères

Which translates literally into "Like our fathers" but the translation is "Let us all together"
then the next

> Chantons en vrais amis!

Which translates literally into "Sing in true friends" but is translated into "Sing *as* true friends"

And a line earlier which is

> Ce diable à quatre
>   A le triple talent

which translates literally into "This devil at/to four has the triple talent" but translates into "This fourfold devil with three talents"

Comment: « Vive Henri IV » has never / cannot ever be considered a "first French national anthem". All that can be said is that it was popular among some royalists at some time in the past. If you want to use the word anthem then you should write "a French royalist anthem" (and not national...) and even then I'm not sure it would be accuraet. (I'm not a historian).

Comment: Ah, thank you for that answer. Sort of unnecessary, but I saw that "D'être un vert galant" translates into "womaniser" which I find is interesting since green used to be a symbol of sexuality, and rule breaking, so basically "Sexual/barbaric galant".

Comment: *Vert Galant* was the nickname given to Henry IV for whom the song was written. And he is said to have been a womaniser.

Comment: Oh then I'm guessing he wasn't very nice haha (alike most kings and queens of that time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Partis* means "factions", so "spouses" seems an excellent choice of words since factions were made through alliances and marriages. In the translation of songs and poetry, prosody has to be taken into account ("spouses" rhymes with "glasses" and "lilies" – the lily was the French symbol of royalty).

*Chantons en vrais amis* literally means "Let's sing as if we were true friends".

*Ce diable à quatre* would probably need a FL question by itself. We expect something after "quatre" but it is cut short probably to keep the rhyme (*quatre*/*battre*). I have found a [presentation of this song](http://www.henriiv.culture.fr/medias/fr/pdf/0/756_10.pdf) in a teacher's guide and it says that *Ce diable à quatre* means *coquin** (a seducer) which is in keeping with the "vert galant". I would say translating by "fourfold devil" is just as obscure as the French *diable à quatre*.

* *Coquin* can also mean "scoundrel" – but that's not what it means here.

Comment: _Diable à quatre_ seems to be a frozen expression: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Diable_%C3%A0_quatre

Comment: @Unfrancophone Tu devrais en faire une réponse parce que ça change ma réponse ! J'ai regardé le wiktionnaire et trouvé en plus "au carré",

Comment: Hmm “wheinc”? Can't guess what you meant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez oops...

Comment: "Un beau partit" is also someone that is interesting in marrying, either for financial or social reasons.

Comment: _Une [diablerie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diablerie) à quatre personnages._